# Crop Image at the bottom and add a Text

Tags: html, css

**How can I crop an image at the bottom and put text there?**

[image: This is the model]

**I've only managed something like this so far:**

[image]

**This is my code:**

```css
    #intro {
        height: 100%;
    }

    #intro {
        background: url("")no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        background-color: #24355C;
    }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .navbar:not(.top-nav-collapse) {
            background-color: #24355C;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 850px) {
        .navbar:not(.top-nav-collapse) {
            background-color: #24355C;
        }
    }
```

```
    <div id="intro" class="view">
        <div class="mask rgba-black-strong">
            <div class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <h2 class="display-4 font-weight-bold white-text pt-5 mb-2">Travel</h2>
                        <hr class="hr-light">
                        <h4 class="white-text my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                            Deleniti
                            consequuntur.</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-white">Read more<i class="fa fa-book ml-2"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a possibility to cut the image at the bottom and can I write text?
Without blue and yellow part

Comment: You could either photoshop/gimp the image itself or you can overlap other elements on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

### ;) try this

```css
.container{
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 background-color:#000;  
}
.img-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center top;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 350px;
  position: relative;
}

.img-container h3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(243, 134, 223, 0.43);
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin:0;
  width: auto;
  height: 10%;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-preview {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="img-container">
            <img class="img-container img-preview" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
            <h3>Hola Amigoooooooooooo</h3>
      </div>

  </div>
```